# SSIS: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Preface: SSIS packages are deployed on SQL server, say serv1, and in these packages connections are made,using windows authentication, to another SQL server, serv2. And

1. I am using windows authentication, a domain account, to login on serv1
2. This account also has login on serv2, although through different windows group
3. SPN are registered for both SQL server's service accounts and delegation is ON.
4. auth_scheme is kerberos. Although for service accounts **NTLM** is being used because network layer protocol is `Shared memory`. And for other domain accounts `kerberos, TCP` is being used.

While executing these packages, they fail with error message `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ ANONYMOUS LOGON'`. All solutions to this scenario point to **Double Hop problem**. Everywhere the solution includes the steps mentioned above. Is there anything that I am missing here.

Comment: How are the packages being executed?  Via sql agent?

Comment: Packages are executed from SSISDB. Just Right Click and execute package.

Comment: Package on sql server 1 makes connection to sql server 2. In this situation why is kerberos required? Where is the double hop ? Are you using linked server?

Answer (score 0):

While you could probably figure out the kerberos issue, I generally avoid the issue altogether.  Here are a few ways that you might address it:

1. Execute the package with SQL Agent under the sql agent service account, if the service account is a Group managed service account (GMSA) or an actual domain account.  A login can be created for the account on the target server.  GMSA accounts provide an extra level of security - more on that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/group-managed-service-accounts-overview.
2. Execute the package with SQL Agent under a proxy account.  This stores the credentials in SQL Server and is easier to do if you do not have the permissions to change the account for the sql agent service.  More on setting up a proxy here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver15.  Once the proxy account is created, you'll be able to select as an option in the sql agent job
3. You could change the connections to use SQL authentication, though the options above are preferred in terms of security. This would be an option if you do not have sql agent for some reason.

Comment: I  assmue that the option 2 (proxy account) will still have the double hop issue?

Comment: Please also could you explain what you think is hop 1 and hop 2 in the current question?

Comment: If you RDP into Serv1, then I don't know where the doublehop is coming from.  However, if you are connected to it from your machine, then it's a hop to serv1 and then another to Serv2.  @variable, as you noted, it could also be an issue within the package using a linked server.  Option 2 above avoids the doublehop by storing the creds on Serv1.  It's essentially the same thing as option 1, but a different place to store the creds